# ElasticSearch must_not query return score=1 not 0

Tags: elasticsearch

I found some description about `must_not` in the [`official document`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

> `must_not` The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents. Clauses are executed in filter context meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching. Because scoring is ignored, a score of **0** for all documents is returned.

It told me that the `must_not` will return a **0** score just like the `filter` operation. But when I execute this query:

```
GET /my_idx/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {"match" : {"name": "Test"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

the response shows:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 6,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_idx",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "Nbs5nmkBAfzcjFMf2czR",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "analyzer": "my_tokenizer",
          "text": "Doe"
        }
      },
...
```

As you can see the `"_score": 1`

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you only have a must_not in the filter, an invisible match_all is present. What s why you got the _score = 1.

Comment: I use ```"filter": {"match_all": {}}``` and I got the ```_score=0```, thanks!